# One set of PHP files connecting to one of many databases

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to figure out a good, secure way to have a single directory of files (one instance of our application) connect to a single database out of a range of multiple possibilities. The way we used to do things was each customer had one set of files and one database, and their set of files would be configured to link directly to their database. This works, however it's been making it difficult to keep a standardized version of the application across all customers; ensuring everyone has the latest updates.

The one way I was thinking of tackling it was to have a unique, generic database that's used for the login process. Within that database would be a field that contains the name of the user's specific database, which would then be stored in their session. Once they've logged in the application would then look to the session to get the name of their database, and connect to that directly.

I'm pretty sure that approach would work, I'm just worried that it could have some security faults. Any advice on how to handle this?

Comment: absolutely doubt about your DB security with your strategy!

Comment: Why aren't you using configuration files to store the credentials?

Comment: @Polynomial Could you clarify that a bit? We are using a file that manages the connection to the database, and it's different for each user. But again, each user has their own set of files, which we want to reduce to a single set of files for all users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you need to know per customer is the user, pass, dbname, and hostname for the database connection. I'd simply store these in a configuration file, one per customer, named according to the customer:

```
/path/to/configs/customer1.ini
/path/to/configs/customer2.ini
/path/to/configs/customer3.ini
```

Then your app picks which config file to load based on an environment variable set in the VHOST or even by the value in $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].

For example, your index.php might have something like:

```
if (!preg_match('/pattern to ensure valid hostname/', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
    exit;
}
$config = '/path/to/configs/' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '.ini';
if (!file_exists($config)) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
    exit;
}
require_once $config;
```

Then create:

```
/path/to/configs/customer.com.ini
```

as:

```
dbname = whatever
user = whatever
pass = whatever
dbhost = whatever
```

(Er, sorry, you wouldn't require_once an ini file, but you get the idea...)

Comment: I'm liking this approach! However the example you gave looks like it'd only work if each customer had their own domain, and we're going to have one domain for all users. Currently they access their application through example.com/customer, is there a way I could simulate that AND set it up for configuration files?

Comment: Sure, just pull the customer name from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` instead of `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used Wordpress MU? They have solved this kind of issue cleverly and clearly. They have used `oAuth` and `Cookies`, instead of storing them in `sessions`.

If you are not able to use `oAuth`, I guess the best alternative would be `cookies`. Use `domain cookies` and something similar to Apache's `Virtual Hosts`, you can have all the authentication details from MySQL, as you said which references the tables and based on the domain / username, you can use the instance.

We call this concept as Multi tenant application.

Comment: can you link to any source/tut? tnx

Comment: @sree I have seen WPMU source code and they have done the similar one. I just explained this. If it is needed, give me sometime, I will write a tutorial on this and post it. I have implemented same kind of concept using SAML.

Comment: tnx praveen.. look forward for that... :)